# How to convert optimized_graph.lite file to .tflite file?

Tags: android, tensorflow, firebase-mlkit, tensorflow-android

I followed the steps mentioned in the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2-tflite/) and generated optimized_graph.lite file successfully. 
As per documentation we need TensorFlow Lite model for inference in a mobile app in the form of a .tflite file.

How do we further generate the .tflite file?

Comment: before you execute the command to get the lite file try changing it's extension to --`output_file=tf_files/optimized_graph.tflite` or simply when you try to load the graph from your assets in android studio just use the .lite version and see if it works

Comment: The demo doesn't work when the extension is changed to .tflite .It works fine with .lite file.However I need the .tflite for another app and not the codelab.

Comment: I think it's safe to say the .lite file will work in other apps. Give it a try ..

Answer (score 2):

The generated `optimized_graph.lite` *is* the `tflite` flatbuffer file. In this codelab, for some reason they chose to use the `.lite` filename extension as opposed to `.tflite`.

So simply copy the `optimized_graph.lite` file and rename it to `optimized_graph.tflite` and you should be able to use it further to upload to firebase console or place in the assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as .tflite file , i searched the codelab project and did not find anything called a .tflite file.You only require `tf_files/optimized_graph.lite`.

Comment: Yes the codelab demo works optimized_graph.lite But I need a tflite file for custom trained model which can be uploaded on firebase console or can be placed in the assets folder.

Comment: Why do you a need a .tflite file? You can use the .lite file.